# Calling remote session bean in Payara Server - where to put the remote beans remote interface in Netbeans project?

Tags: netbeans, ejb, payara

I'm trying to start a new project using Netbeans (16 and 17) and a Payara 6.
My first tests is around getting the session beans to call eachother.
There are two beans a and b. I can call bean a from a Swing GUI and the only thing bean a is doing is injecting bean b with a @EJB annotation and calling a method thats in the Remote interface of b.

To get the compiler to find bean b I have added it to the library of bean a. Compilation works. When deploying bean a a get this result in Payara:

[image: 1]

That means that bean b (CalledBean) somehow already is deployed. I want bean b to be in a seperate EAR-file but when I try to deploy that EAR a get an error that the name CalledBean is allready used. And it is from bean a but I don't want that, I want to keep different beans in certain EAR-files independen of who is calling them.

I don't want the Netbeans project to end up with creating beans based on jar files in the library directory.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

/Jan

I have tried to mix whit the jar, removing the bean class and only keeping the remote interface but no luck.
I have spent hours on googling for this but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Netbeans 16 and 17 together with JakartaEE 10 and Payara 6 is not ready :-(
I have to manually change the javax package to jakarta after I have created sessionbeans and that is OK but there are a lot of other issues that are not solved yet like the possibility to deploy from Netbeans.

To get rid of the creation of bean b I had to make a jar-file containing only the remote interface and use that as an library. I wrote a 2-line cmd-file to fix that.
I am now up and running and can continue my experiments with JakartaEE 10.